# Collection in class module

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I'm working with VBA class modules for the first time. I've been searching for hours now, but couldn't find a working solution for my problem. Somehow VBA won't let me add my object to another object's collection.

I have three classes, *cReferenceList* contains a collection of *cReference*, each *cReference* contains a collection of *cPackaging* objects. The implementations look like this:

**cReferenceList**

```
Option Explicit

Private AllReferences As New Collection

Public Sub Add(ref As cReference)
    AllReferences.Add (ref)
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(myItem As Variant)
    AllReferences.Remove (myItem)
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = AllReferences.Count
End Property

Public Property Get getAllReferences() As Collection
    Set getAllReferences = AllReferences
End Property

Public Property Get getSingleReference(myItem As Variant) As cReference
    Set getSingleReference = AllReferences(myItem)
End Property
```

**cReference**

```
Option Explicit

Private Packvorschriften As New Collection
Private strName As String

Public Property Let setName(newName As String)
    strName = newName
End Property
Public Property Get getName() As String
    getName = strName
End Property

Public Sub Add(ByVal pkg As cPackaging)
    Packvorschriften.Add pkg, pkg.getName()
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(myItem As Variant)
    Packvorschriften.Remove (myItem)
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = Packvorschriften.Count
End Property

Public Property Get getAllPackagings() As Collection
    Set getAllPackagings = Packvorschriften
End Property

Public Property Get getSinglePackaging(myItem As Variant) As cPackaging
    Set getSinglePackaging = Packvorschriften(myItem)
End Property
```

**cPackaging**

```
Option Explicit

Private strName As String
Private intMinMenge As Integer
Private intMaxMenge As Integer

Public Property Let setName(newName As String)
    strName = newName
End Property
Public Property Get getName() As String
    getName = strName
End Property
Public Property Let setMinMenge(MinMenge As Integer)
    intMinMenge = MinMenge
End Property
Public Property Get MinMenge() As Integer
    MinMenge = intMinMenge
End Property

Public Property Let setMaxMenge(MaxMenge As Integer)
    intMaxMenge = MaxMenge
End Property
Public Property Get MaxMenge() As Integer
    MaxMenge = intMaxMenge
End Property
```

The Problem occurs when I try to add a cPackaging to cReference.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetExistingReferences() As cReferenceList

Dim refList As cReferenceList, newRef As cReference, newPackaging As cPackaging
Set refList = New cReferenceList

'other variables     

 For i = 1 To intLastRow    

   Set newRef = New cReference
   newRef.setName = wksReferenzliste.Cells(i + 6, 1).text

    …. find data for new packaging

            Set newPackaging = New cPackaging
            With newPackaging
                .setName = wksReferenzliste.Cells(...).text
                .setMinMenge = CInt(wksReferenzliste.Cells(...).Value)
                .setMaxMenge = CInt(wksReferenzliste.Cells(...).Value)
            End With
            newRef.Add (newPackaging)

    refList.Add (newRef)
    Set newRef = Nothing
Next i

GetExistingReferences = refList
End Function
```

The line `newRef.Add (newPackaging)` leads to the error message 'Object does not support this property or method'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Remove the parentheses.

```
Public Sub Add(ref As cReference)
    AllReferences.Add ref
End Sub
```

Otherwise you are trying to add to the collection the value of the **default property** of your `cReference` instance, but you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick note on property Get/Set/Let

In your code you have, as an example

```
Public Property Let setName(newName As String)
    strName = newName
End Property
Public Property Get getName() As String
    getName = strName
End Property
```

Which you are using to manage the content of StrName.  This is in fact an imcorrect use of the property structure in VBA.

In VBA the purpose of the property structure is to allow the same name to be used for both the Get and Set/Let operations.  Otherwise we would just use the type of naming convention you have used together with Functions and Subs.

Hence your code would be more conventionally written as

```
Public Property Let Name(byval Value As String)
    strName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = strName
End Property
```

Then the property  Name can be used in exactly the same way as you would use a normal variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I appreciate it.